# "would be free" vs "will be free"

Tags: will-would, future, would

How should I use 'would' or 'will' in a conditional sentence about planning a meeting?

I'm trying to arrange a meeting with someone at the university tomorrow, but I'm uncertain about their availability. Probably even he is not sure if he can make some free time tomorrow or not (We are both uncertain). Which one is the correct from?

- We can meet tomorrow if you would be free.
- We can meet tomorrow if you will be free.

Comment: Neither. Idiomatically, [we're far more likely](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tomorrow+if+you+are%2Ctomorrow+if+you+will+be%2Ctomorrow+if+you+would+be&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) to say *"...if you **are** free"*. It doesn't really make any difference how confident the speaker or the addressee is at time of speaking, that he either will or won't be free the next day.

Comment: if you are *possibly* free tomorrow. But this is find the right word. Generally, will and would are not used after if. If you want, I will see you. If you wanted, I would see you.